Changing command order in Python's Typer
I want Typer to display my commands in the order I have initialized them and it displays those commands in alphabetic order.
I have tried different approaches including this one: https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/246
In this I get AssertionError. Others like subclassing some Typer and click classes does actually nothing.
I want the commands to be in the same order as in this working piece of code:
import typer
import os

app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def change_value(file_name, field):
    print("Here I will change the", file_name, field)


@app.command()
def close_field(file_name, field):
    print("I will close field")


@app.command()
def add_transaction(file_name):
    print("I will add the transaction")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()


Please help :)

Please show the full error and traceback, and the code that's getting it.

I found the solution myself, @Barmar

You should still put the details in the question so the context of the answer will make sense.

The question makes sense without the details you requested :) I specified one line of text, so that the question is less misleading :)

All right I have found solution elsewhere, while trying to post the ticket to Typer (they have a really comprehensive troubleshooting!)
https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/428
The app that displays commands in the order I want them displayed looks like this:
import typer
from click import Context
from typer.core import TyperGroup

class OrderCommands(TyperGroup):
  def list_commands(self, ctx: Context):
    return list(self.commands)

app = typer.Typer(
    cls=OrderCommands,
    no_args_is_help=True
)


@app.command()
def change_value(file_name, field):
    print("Here I will change the", file_name, field)


@app.command()
def close_field(file_name, field):
    print("I will close field")


@app.command()
def add_transaction(file_name):
    print("I will add the transaction")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()

